# Visual C++ statement with mixture of operators priority

Tags: visual-c++, operators

I have this problem using Visual Studio 2017:

```
int x = 2, y = -3;
cout << ((--x + y && y++ - x) || x-- + (--y + x++)) << endl;
cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << endl << endl;
```

It always shows that the result of the whole statement is 1 (which is OK) and that x = 1 and y = -2.

What I don't understand is how can **y** by equal to **-2**? In my calculation it should be **-3**!

I referenced to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right-hand side of the `||` operator is not performed because the left-hand side expression `&&` operator evaluates to true.

So only `y++` has taken place, leaving it as -2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but here are my views:

```
cout << ((--x + y && y++ - x) || x-- + (--y + x++)) << endl;
```

`((--x + y && y++ - x)` resolves to `-4` which is non zero and hence is true. So `x-- + (--y + x++))` don't have to be checked and no need to execute that code.

in the expression `(--x + y && y++ - x)` there is a --x so that will result in a decrement in x and y++ will result in an increment in y, ie. y=-3+1.